# Pushing variable to an array depending on the checkbox selected

Tags: javascript

I have an simple example here, the check boxes were already given by the framework we are using so it just checks weather it is checked or not(returns true or false). And I have three variables with different options that will be pushed in an array and gets removed when unchecked. By the way I have made it worked but I think there is more proper way to do this.

```
var chk1 = data.config.chk1; // returns true or false only
var chk2 = data.config.chk2; // same as above
var chk3 = data.config.chk3;
var settA = "settingsA";
var settB = "settingsB";
var settC = "settingsC";

if (chk1) {
  arr.push(settA)
}
if (chk2) {
  arr.push(settB)
}
if (chk3) {
  arr.push(settC);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I would eidt your Object that contains the `chk#` keys (with true or false values) with the actual settings value instead. Then if its in the object you know its true. That way you can make your code easier to handle like so.

```
var Chks = data.config; 

for(var key in Chks)
  arr.push(Chks[key])
```

Now if your object contained `data.config.chk3 = 'SettingsA'` your array will contain `'SettingsA'`.

Maybe this wont work for you, but as a rule of thumb if your repeating the same commands over and over you should probably abstract, like use an itterator.